# Bad performance Core Data CONTAINS predicate

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad, core-data

I'm using the NSFetchedResultsController to show some search results in a UITableView. The search results are requested by the following predicate:

```
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(plainText CONTAINS %@)", _searchString]
```

The entity where the search is going through has about 25.000 objects. The plainText property contains a String value with approximately 700 words each.

This search takes about 20 seconds wich is way too slow.

Is there any way to optimize the performance?

I watched the WWDC 2010 Session 137 where she is talking about normalizing the keywords into a separate entity to avoid using CONTAINS. This is a way to improve it, only I have 700 keywords each. Making it 700 x 25.000 = 17.500.000 keywords. I doubt it will improve. Should I even try?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Searching 700-word attribute in 25,000 entities for a string will indeed be slow, yes. Your wwdc idea is correct - you'd want to make a separate entity which is a single 'keyword', with a to-many relationship back to your entities. That way, you will very quickly find the one keyword entity, and then very quickly find the entities out of your 25,000. This way you'll avoid searching through every very long string.

tldr; yes, you should try

Comment: Although the idea is very functional indeed, I'd be cautious to whether the size of the database matters, for this method is going to increase it's size immensely.

Comment: Won't know until you try. It could _lower_ the size, since each keyword will exist once. You'd store roughly ~700 * 2 * sizeof(primary key) for each entity - the relationship table would have the pk of the entity and the pk of the keyword. But you'd get rid of 700 * (average length of word). I bet it'd be just about a wash.

Comment: Hi Colin, thanks for your answer. I did created the Keyword entity with a many-to-many relationship to the Part entity (originally containing the text). Now I need the fastest query for getting the parts containing all queried keywords. I tried it with a NSFetchRequest on the Keywords entity with predicate (word == \"testword\" AND word = \"testword2\") this way I do get the keywords quickly. Only when I then loop through the keywords and get there parts then it takes a long time. Do you know a faster way to do this?

Comment: AND? That doesn't make sense. You mean OR? In any case, don't do it that way - do a fetch request for your parts entity, look up how to use ANY in the predicate.

Comment: You'll need a many to many relationship from parts to keywords (and vice-versa if you want to go that way).